# GitHub actions sfdx-actions/setup-sfdx step hangs when running the workflow

Tags: github, salesforce, command-line-interface, github-actions, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to use sfdx-actions/setup-sfdx (https://github.com/sfdx-actions/setup-sfdx ) to connect to sandbox salesforce DX as part of a GitHub action. From there, I will be using the SFDX auth url when running tests across Salesforce.

However, whenever I try to use setup-sfdx as part of GitHub actions, the step just hangs for hours.

I have successfully retrieved my auth url in the format `force://<clientId>:<clientSecret>:<refreshToken>@<instanceUrl>` and saved it as a GitHub secret (named ORG_AUTH_SECRET).

I am using a GitHub actions workflow yaml file that uses a self-hosted runner.

See below excerpt of the jobs section:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted

    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - name: Checkout repository files 
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Install SFDX and authenticate to org
        uses: sfdx-actions/setup-sfdx@v1
        with:
          sfdx-auth-url: ${{ secrets.ORG_AUTH_SECRET }}

      - name: EnvtUrl
        id: envtUrl
        run: |
          pwd
          ls -a 
          sfdx force:org:display --verbose --json > orgDetails.json
          cat orgDetails.json
          orgUrl=$(jq '.result.instanceUrl' orgDetails.json | sed 's/^.//;s/.$//')
          accessToken=$(jq '.result.accessToken' orgDetails.json | sed 's/^.//;s/.$//')
          frontDoor='/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid='
          echo "::set-output name=url_output::"$orgUrl$frontDoor$accessToken
          echo name > Resources/test.txt
          cat Resources/test.txt

      - name: Run tests
        run: |
          echo Running tests
          pwd
          ls -a
          chmod +x DAIRunner
          ./Runner -v testname http://192.168.214.170:8000/ 
          echo tests complete.
```

Any help would be so much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to run

`sudo npm install sfdx-cli --global` on self hosted machine. I think when you already have installed a sfdx on that machine probably you dont need to use

`sfdx-actions/setup-sfdx@v1`

just run command like you do in next step

Answer (score 0):

You can also install sfdx using the below commands if you're using a linux host that doesn't have npm

```
- name: Install sfdx
  run: |
    wget https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx/channels/stable/sfdx-linux-arm.tar.xz
    mkdir /sfdx
    tar xJf sfdx-linux-arm.tar.xz -C /sfdx --strip-components 1
    PATH=/sfdx/bin:$PATH
```